# NSRangeException error when using Stack Navigator (Expo)

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I am trying to make a Stack Navigation in my Expo app, but when I use it I get this error when I try to open it on my phone:

```
NSRangeException: *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array

RCTFatalException
facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::callSerializableNativeHook(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&)
facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::callSerializableNativeHook(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&)
facebook::react::JSIExecutor::nativeCallSyncHook(facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)
non-virtual thunk to reanimated::ReanimatedHermesRuntime::~ReanimatedHermesRuntime()
std::__1::function<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)>::operator()(facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long) const
facebook::hermes::HermesRuntimeImpl::HFContext::func(void*, hermes::vm::Runtime&, hermes::vm::NativeArgs)
hermes::vm::NativeFunction::_nativeCall(hermes::vm::NativeFunction*, hermes::vm::Runtime&)
hermes::vm::Interpreter::handleCallSlowPath(hermes::vm::Runtime&, hermes::vm::PinnedHermesValue*)
hermes::vm::CallResult<hermes::vm::HermesValue, (hermes::vm::detail::CallResultSpecialize)2> hermes::vm::Interpreter::interpretFunction<false, false>(hermes::vm::Runtime&, hermes::vm::InterpreterState&)
hermes::vm::Runtime::interpretFunctionImpl(hermes::vm::CodeBlock*)
hermes::vm::Runtime::runBytecode(std::__1::shared_ptr<hermes::hbc::BCProviderBase>&&, hermes::vm::RuntimeModuleFlags, llvh::StringRef, hermes::vm::Handle<hermes::vm::Environment>, hermes::vm::Handle<hermes::vm::HermesValue>)
facebook::hermes::HermesRuntimeImpl::evaluatePreparedJavaScript(std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::jsi::PreparedJavaScript const> const&)
facebook::hermes::HermesRuntime::evaluateJavaScriptWithSourceMap(std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::jsi::Buffer const> const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::jsi::Buffer const> const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const&)
facebook::hermes::HermesRuntimeImpl::evaluateJavaScript(std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::jsi::Buffer const> const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const&)
facebook::react::HermesExecutor::HermesExecutor(std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::jsi::Runtime>, std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::react::ExecutorDelegate>, std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::react::MessageQueueThread>, std::__1::function<void (std::__1::function<void ()> const&, std::__1::function<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> ()>)> const&, std::__1::function<void (facebook::jsi::Runtime&)>)
facebook::react::JSIExecutor::loadBundle(std::__1::unique_ptr<facebook::react::JSBigString const, std::__1::default_delete<facebook::react::JSBigString const>>, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>)
facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::getDecoratedNativeMethodCallInvoker(std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::react::NativeMethodCallInvoker>) const
facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::getDecoratedNativeMethodCallInvoker(std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::react::NativeMethodCallInvoker>) const
facebook::react::tryAndReturnError(std::__1::function<void ()> const&)
facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::tryFunc(std::__1::function<void ()> const&)
facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::runAsync(std::__1::function<void ()>)
5A6C1F41-BF70-32F6-A1D6-5B894DD21362
5A6C1F41-BF70-32F6-A1D6-5B894DD21362
5A6C1F41-BF70-32F6-A1D6-5B894DD21362
CFRunLoopRunSpecific
RCTConvertArrayValue
5623831D-5719-33A9-9691-759F47D714D1
_pthread_start
thread_start
```

here is the App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
// import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
// import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import LandingPage from './components/LandingPage';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName='Landing' ///the name of the initial screen
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Landing" component={LandingPage} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

And if needed the quickly drawn up LandingPage:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
//import SpinningEarth from './SpinningEarth';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { colors, commonStyles } from '../styles/commonStyles';

const LandingPage = () => {
  // const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: colors.background }}>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', marginBottom: 20 }}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 24, color: 'blue' }}>Town</Text>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 24, color: 'green' }}>Trekkr</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
        <Button title="Sign Up" />
        <Button title="Login" />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default LandingPage;
```

If I were to comment out all the StackNavigation and just have my App.js return `<LandingPage />` it works just fine and displays the landing page. I am planning on adding more pages to the navigation but I tested with another page in the stack and got the same error as well. I've tried googling for this error but can not find anything relatively related to where my issue arises. Could it be that the Stack is not being initialized properly? I have followed the React-Native / Expo guide for the stack navigator (installed all the needed dependencies, etc).

Comment: Did you install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context?

Comment: @CanerKuru Yes i have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code I see no problem, try below step to run the app

- import this on top your app.js

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```

- remove node_modules, yarn.lock, or package.lock
- reinstall everything again using yarn or npm
- try check compatible version for expo with `npx expo install --check`
- remove all apk installation if you have except expo go
- run it with `npx expo start -c` to clear all cache

sometimes you just need to clear the dep and cache to run the app, do this regularly if you face any issue.

let me know if still face this issue.

reference: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've actually done all of these steps before posting here, ultimately I believe the problem lies in a monorepo attempt that somewhere along the way failed to keep track of the dependencies between projects. Therefore, it was pointing at the wrong dependency area which probably was why it was crashing with that error. It's my only assumption, however, since I believe your answer to be correct I will mark it as so. I just stopped with the monorepo idea and split it into its own and it is now working again, it was fun while it lasted. It worked until i tried to add nav.

Comment: Thank you, maybe there's something wrong with other code in other screen that causing the issue..

Comment: I thought so as well, however, if I remove the stack navigator imports and the code itself it goes back to working fine. In the node modules of the app, it installed navigation, but then in the main node modules (shared between another app) it install navigation there and the stack dependencies... not sure what happened to get the linkage all misconfigured but couldn't find the underlying issue. Oh well, it happens.

Comment: Please share your package or min code project that not working so I can check..